How can I specify flags for CMAKE_<LANG>_HOST_COMPILER?
CMake has a set of variables named CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS etc.) which are used when building command-lines for compiling targets with the compilers for those respective languages. It also has corresponding CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER, which determines which compiler is actually used for each of those languages.
This is all fine and good, but - there is another context in which we select a compiler with a variable, and that is for multi-pass/multi-compiler compilation cases, like that of CUDA and HIP: There's the "compiler driver", or "meta-compiler" if you will, like nvcc, which serves as the CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER; and it relegates host-side-code (as opposed to GPU-side-code) compilation to a C++ compiler. CMake supports this, with its CMAKE_<LANG>_HOST_COMPILER variables.
However - I haven't figured out how to specify the default flags for the CMAKE_<LANG>_HOST_COMPILER's, as opposed to CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER's - as there is no CMAKE_<LANG>_HOST_FLAGS variables. How do I do that? And why are those variables missing?

Usually setting CMAKE__FLAGS is a bad idea and allowed to change only in a toolchain files. target_compile_options() is recommended.

@273K: 1. Indeed, that's true - and still, these variables are not deprecated 2. That would be a separate question: Where is the target_host_compile_option() command?

You misunderstand how target_compile_options() works. Target compile options are appended to either CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS for CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER or to nothing for CMAKE_<LANG>_HOST_COMPILER. target_host_compile_option() is not needed.

@273K: I understood exactly what you've written, and - target_host_compile_option() is definitely needed. Perhaps you've misunderstood what I'm trying to achieve.

Does the $<COMPILE_LANGUAGE> generator expression help solve your problem?

@AlexReinking: I don't see how it would...

@273K re your first comment, that would be CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_CONFIG_INIT. CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS is something for the person running config. Ex. something you'd put in a preset. if you mean setting via set() is bad, sure. if you mean setting via -D in configure is bad, no.

@user: Ah, ok, I see. Yes, that makes sense. I had not even noticed that was introduced with CMake 3.11 ... I mostly stick to setting individual target flags. But I wanted to make the question simpler rather than cover multiple aspects of the mechanism for setting options.

@273K re your second comment, no. it appends to the COMPILE_OPTIONS and/or INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS target properties. CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS is kind of a thing on its own. these facts are pretty clearly stated in the docs.

I couldn't figure out any way to specify this, so I opened a new CMake issue: Issue #25911.. and I hope it gets addressed.
